# how to round only top two corners in my case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have created a round corner drawable resource `round_corner_bg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

I applied it to my `LinearLayout` :

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner_bg"
...
```

It works fine. However, it rounded all four corners, how can I make it to only round the top left and top right corner?

Comment: Please search first before posting question here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change the following:

```
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
```

To:

```
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the corner tag as shown below

```
<corners android:topLeftRadius="10dip" android:topRightRadius="10dip"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- you can use any color you want -->
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="0.6dp" android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
```

with

```
<corners android:topRightRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
```

Change value as per side you want